# jQuery Sortable, clone and appendTo, helper disappearing

Tags: jquery-ui, append, clone, jquery-ui-sortable, helper

Question is that the clone helper on jQuery Sortable is not showing itself with the following settings:-

```
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        items: "li",
        helper: "clone",
        appendTo: "body",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
```

Essentially, the placeholder is being shown, but the actual helper cloned element is not.

appendTo and helper are necessary because without the helper and appendTo, when I seek to drag the LI element, the `li` element will sometimes disappear and be deleted when dropped.

I can confirm there is no overflow css on the parent `<ul>` and that the disappearing `<li>` also happens when `appendTo` is set to `parent`. Containment did not prevent the `<li>` from disappearing.

I am using jQuery UI 1.10.2. Anyone konw how to address this?

**EDIT:** To be clear, I've identified that the item is disappearing into a child sortable, because there are intersecting divs in the list structure containing child sortable elements.

Is it possible to reject an LI element with a certain class from a sortable? Whats happening is that the LI is dropping into the child sortable even though it has no `connectWith` The LI needs to only be sortable inside its parent sortable and not try to insert itself in a child sortable (they even have separate ids and separate classes so not sure why this is happening).

Answer (score 0):

Partial Solution:

```
stop: function(event, ui){
if(ui.item.parent().attr('id') !== 'sortable'){
  $("#sortable").sortable("cancel");
  }
},
```

If anyone has a better solution, please do let me know.